# How to have a pdf open when clicking on a wordpress site page title

Tags: wordpress, pdf

I'm trying to set up our wordpress page to automatically display a pdf when a user clicks on the page title.

Here is the example we are trying to emulate

On the Carlmont H.S. foundation website, under the Our Supporters tab, if you click on "2015-2106 Honor Roll", it directly links to:

http://www.carlmontacademicfoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/2015-16-Donor-Roll.pdf

Here is our website:

http://www.aragonfund.org/

If you click on donors the page opens and displays at plugin that displays the PDF.  We are wanting it to just open directly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to pages, add a new page, change your permlink to yourpagename.pdf
2. Store your pdf at your wordpress, media
3. at the menu link, use yourpagename.pdf link then save your menu link and publish.
4. Go to the page and add your pdf file as open on-page link using the HTML Constructor widget plugin.

Comment: I'm not finding the HTML Construtor widget plugin to add to my site

Comment: You must install some plugins:
Page Builder by SiteOrigin 
SiteOrigin CSS
SiteOrigin Widgets Bundle
Black Studio TinyMCE Widget
TinyMCE Advanced
With that plugins, you will be able to add HTML Constructor.